# Should we ban AI-generated answers?

Tags: discussion, status-review, answers, rules

*Note: I haven't seen any instances of this, nor do I think it is currently an issue, but I do feel it is worth considering, especially if this site goes public*

I'm proposing that answers created using AI, including ChatGPT, are not allowed. AI-answers have a number of issues

- They often *look right*, but are actually wrong despite looking convincing
- Some users post them as an "easy" way to try to gain reputation
- (Most) people come here expecting answers written by humans, not chatbots, and that can be confusing

Therefore, I think that we should explicitly disallow AI-generated answers.

Thoughts? Agree? Disagree?

Comment: [Is there a list of ChatGPT or other AI-related discussions and policies for our sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384922/1099857) contains the list of network-wide conversations for reference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Yes

We should absolutely ban AI-generated answers. Many of the questions here have somewhat subjective answers, and I'm sure there will be questions in the future involving niche languages. An AI would be likely to generate seemingly correct and useful advice that turns out to be at least partially nonsense.

StackOverflow has [already done this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1), and we should absolutely do it too.

Answer (score -6):

## Answers completly generated by AI

Yes. First, its plagarism. Second, we are not a site generated by AI knowledge, but by **human** knowledge. Third, its often wrong. See the other answer for more reasons

## Using AI as a search tool

Searching up the answers to questions is hard ([citation not needed](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-so-hard-to-ask-a-question-on-Stack-Overflow-that-doesnt-get-negative-ratings), but please, why do people ask questions about Stack Exchange on Quora). ChatGPT is good as searching through lots of information and organizing it usefully but often incorrectly (I got it to write a full length novel with a bunch of prompts). For example, on pro-con questions GPT will spit out a lot of pros and cons. Then the human **needs to actually look over the information and do some research** but can then take some of the pros/cons it gives and use them (**but at the minimum parasphrase, preferably do complete own research**). I think this should be allowed and would work for many type sof questions to make answering easier.

Answer (score -7):

## Mostly

For all the reasons you listed. Although, in some cases, LLMs might be able to come up with syntax options.

Comment: That's a good use case. We could make an exception for that, perhaps people could say for those "ChatGPT came up with this idea for decorator syntax"?